# Different views on each different iphone, using sizing classes?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, size-classes

I have a screen with a lot of buttons, however I want to show more buttons on bigger devices.

Looking at the sizing classes I can't achieve what I need, to uninstall them.
I need to have different about of buttons on iphone 4, 5, 6 and 6+.

iPhone 4 - 12 buttons
iPhone 5s - 12 buttons
iPhone 6 - 15 buttons
iPhone 6s - 18 buttons

iPhone 6 is part of the custom width but not regular height.

How can I achieve this with a storyboard?

EDIT:

MY layout is three buttons per row.
so:-

iPhone 4 - 4 rows

iPhone 5s - 4 rows

iPhone 6 - 5 rows

iPhone 6s - 6 rows

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if i understood your design but how about using a `collectionView` with `"button" cells`, or a `tableview` (how i said i don't really understand how it should look like), depending on the size of the screen you would have more `cells` thus `buttons`. And with a little bit of mathematics it will be done automatically you will not have to set the number of buttons, of-course again it depends on the design

Comment: `collectionView` is your way my friend - the simplest and the fastest

Comment: Really I thought I could install based on height somehow. Also as I say iPhone 6 has a different number of buttons to the rest of compact width

Comment: you mentioned different amount of rows thus height, not items per row/ width, but still at this point id rather create a costume layout for collection view rather than adding 15 buttons to the view

Comment: I'll have to investigate collection views, not used them so far.